# Inserting today date from form to database

Tags: php, sql

I'm trying to insert date when form is processed but in MySQL is inserting like

> 0000-00-00

I don't want user to insert date.
Here is my form

```
<form action="upload.php" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
<textarea type="text" name="text" cols="40" rows="10"></textarea><br />
<input type="hidden" name="dt"/>
<input type="submit" name="upload" id="upload" value="Изпрати" />
```

And this is upload.php

```
<?php

if (isset($_POST['upload'])) {

$text = $_POST['text'];
$dt = date('Y-m-d', strtotime($_POST['Date']));

        $db = new mysqli("localhost", "*****", "", "****");

        if (mysqli_connect_error()) {
            printf("Connect failed: ", mysqli_connect_error());
        }
        mysqli_set_charset($db, "UTF8");

        $query = "INSERT INTO table (text, date) VALUES (?, ?)";
        $conn = $db->prepare($query);
        if ($conn == TRUE) {
            $conn->bind_param("si",$text, $dt );
            if (!$conn->execute()) {
                echo 'error insert';
            } else {
                header("Location: ../admin/index.php");
                exit;
            }
        } else {
            die("Error preparing Statement");
        }
} else {
    echo 'error';
}
?>
```

What can be the problem?

edit:

In mysql the row for date is type - 'date'

edit2:

I forget about NOW()... is working perfect and is so simple.

Comment: You have `name="dt"` in your form and `$_POST['Date']` in your script.

Comment: Why post the date at all if it's today's date? Just create the date and insert it server-side.

Comment: Not a solution, but why dont you use MySQLs `NOW()`?

Comment: Your from is missing Date and you are using $dt = date('Y-m-d', strtotime($_POST['Date'])); to add in the DB, add the element in the form

Comment: Stupid question, you say `I don't want user to insert date.`, but you use $_POST and a textfield for the user to input something. What EXACTLY do you want now? Date freely changeable by the user or input the current date?

Comment: With NOW() and removed field in form. That's work fine! Thank you!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> I don't want user to insert date.

Then don't make it a part of the user-submitted form.  As it stands, even if it's a `hidden` element, users can modify it to insert whatever date value they want.  You don't want the user to insert the date, but your current code *requires* that the user insert the date.

If you just want it to be a system-known date, you can do this entirely in the `INSERT` statement at the database level:

```
INSERT INTO table (text, date) VALUES (?, NOW())
```

That way the database itself generates the current date, instead of relying on whatever the user submits.  At this point you can completely remove the date `input` from the form and remove the parameter from the PHP code that builds the database query.

Comment: My thoughts exactly. Was about to write that, but well, too slow.^^

Answer (score 1):

if you don't want user to be insert date than handle it at server side. My answer is for handle using `PHP` otherwise you can also go with `NOW()` mysql side handling.Choice up to you :

```
$dt = date('Y-m-d: H:i:s');
```

OR you can store it in databse as timestamp:

```
$dt=date("Y-m-d H:i:s");
$dt= strtotime($dt);
```

and retrieve it at front

```
date("Y-m-d H:i:s",$dt)
```

Comment: Yes, you could, but why? MySQL and PHP both use the same server time, so it will be the same. Doing this in PHP is slower and more vulnerable to errors.

Comment: it is up to him, i have answered in the way he is doing :)

Comment: @HarshalMahajan, thank's for you answer but I will use NOW() as "David" and "Y U NO WORK" suggested.

Comment: Yes sure no problem , i just gave you the alternate way to do it.

Answer (score 0):

Replace in your code:

$query = "INSERT INTO table (text, date) VALUES (?, NOW())";